# vim: change line's font color based upon first character in the line?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

In vim, I'd like to change a font color for just one line depending on if said line starts (with any preceding tab/space/whitespace) a dash, period, slash, or 'x'.  How can I program/configure existing vim to do this?

Comment: That's not really a colorscheme task. That is a task for search highlighting, or syntax highlighting, or match highlighting, depending on how persistent you want it to be, whether you want it to be local to the window or not, and whether you have existing syntax highlighting that might interfere. We need a little more detail on the above.

Comment: I.e. under what circumstances do you want this line highlighted? And why (what are you trying to accomplish with the highlighted line)?

Comment: This plugin might be of use https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides

Comment: I've removed 'colorscheme' from the question.  I hope to provide more context later to answer @Ben's question.

Answer (score 4):

In Vim, a *colorscheme* just provides a mapping of *highlighting groups* (usually generic ones such as `Comment`, `String`, though particular syntaxes also define things like `vimLineComment`) to foreground / background colors and text attributes such as bold or italic. What you want is a custom *syntax definition*.

`:help usr_44.txt` introduces writing a syntax file; you can also look to the existing ones in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/` for inspiration. To highlight lines starting with `x`:

```
:syntax match mysyntaxXLine /^x.*$/
:highlight link mysyntaxXLine Error
```

Comment: What is 'Error' in the 'highlight link' command?  I'm afraid I'm terrible at deciphering vim commands manuals (have looked at the manual plus misc blogs).  Does 'Error' represent some sort of function call?

Comment: No, `Error` is just an example highlight group. See `:hi` output.